# Why isn't superclass error raised in development when class names are the same?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Setting migration class name, same as a model class name doesn’t raise an error in development environment, instead during deployment to production, it raises a `superclass mismatch`.

After lot of research I figured , it might be because of "*Lazy load*", i.e. classes are reloaded for every request in development. Is it correct or is there any other reason altogether.

*Error Message from capistrano*

> superclass mismatch for class SimilarityMatrixInSubjects

*The code snippet*

```
db/migrate/20130915125533_similarity_matrix_in_subjects.rb

class SimilarityMatrixInSubjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :similarity_matrix_in_subjects do |t|
      t.integer :subject_one_id
      t.integer :subject_two_id
      t.integer :similarity_score
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

*what fixed the bug*

https://github.com/shashanksingh/face_rec_server/blob/master/db/migrate/20130915125533_create_similarity_matrix_in_subjects.rb

Answer (score 1):

`superclass mismatch for class SimilarityMatrixInSubjects` error probably means that you already have that class in your codebase, or at least you have it in your environment for some reason.
This happens when you try to reopen the class, subclassing it from the class which is different from the one it was subsclassed before.
And that's why renaming the migration class helps.

Two things:

- I can see that you create similarity_matrix_in_subjects table. Maybe, you have corresponding AR model? If so, the problem is obvious.
- If not, try to output `SimilarityMatrixInSubjects.ancestors` before the class signature in migration - you will see what it was subclassed from before.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hey @roman , thanks for the solution but I as I said in the question,I know why problem occurred  i.e. the migration class was named exactly same as model, sorry if it wasnt clear. My question is why didn’t I get any error during migration in Development ENV.

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't get it.
Well, I think in development migrations folder is not in rails' auto_load_path, while models folder is in.
And each time you referenced that model, correct one was loaded from foler 'models'.

Comment: Did you run the migration locally, by the way? I think it should has failed than

Comment: Yeah, it ran wonderfully on local.[ just fyi ruby is 1.9.3p448, Rails 4.0.0 ]

Comment: The code is open source so you can always check it out :) 395c4587e858bbfdca96e6494a482a1fc2f9ff91 is where the fix for this problem was pushed , repo : https://github.com/shashanksingh/face_rec_server/